# Loop With FOR along with requests.get

Tags: python, loops, python-requests

I have an algorithm below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests

browser =webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/path/geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://brainly.com.br/app/ask?entry=hero&q=python')
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[href*="/tarefa"]')))
html=browser.page_source
#html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
p=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('div.sg-actions-list__hole > a[href*="/tarefa"]'):
    ref=link.get('href')
    rt = ('https://brainly.com.br'+str(ref))
    p.append(rt)
print(p)

for url in p:
    a=requests.get(url,timeout=10)

    print(a.text)
```

Which Basically get links from the page which is set to Url, the algorithm works normal but I need for each link in the list generated it print the `HTML` of that Link:

Alas to do this I'm Using This Loop:

```
for url in p:
        a=requests.get(url,timeout=10)

        print(a.text)
```

So the problem this loop only prints the 1 List Link,I just need to import the `HTML` code from all links.

Comment: You have shown two different indentions for those last four lines of your code; neither is correct.  The `print` needs to be indented to the same level as the `a=` line.

Comment: even backing off yet and not printing everything

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `p`??

Comment: Just store a list with url link and use for flame in requests.get for each link and print the source code of the page.